# JavaFX runnable jar image loading

Tags: image, javafx

I have been trying to make a runnable jar of a game I made on javaFX 
the game runs fine when I run it on eclipse but when I try to run it after
I create the runnable jar it will then give me errors saying that it cannot find 
the images and or that the url inputs are wrong. I have tried everything I dont 
know what else to do!! can anyone help!
I can run the the jar when using absolute paths of images in the disk but I cant
when i have the images inside a source class folder in the package..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi well sorts out that I had to make a package and put the images inside of it 
then I had to use the full path within the package and that worked. =)

here is how I did it

```
public static String loadResource(String image){
         String url =  "com/SnakeGame/Images/"+image;
         return url;
     }
```